# Find out whether the two statements about a stochastic process are equivalent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $\xi_t$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$ be a stochastic process, and $\mathcal{F}_{=t}$, $\mathcal{F}_{\geq t}$, $\ldots$ are $\sigma$-algebras induced by it. I want to find out whether the two following statements are equivalent:

- $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$, $A \in \mathcal{F}_{\leq t}$, $B \in \mathcal{F}_{\geq t}$ a.s.
  $$
  \mathbb{P}\left(AB\mid \mathcal{F}_{=t}\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(A\mid\mathcal{F}_{=t}\right)\mathbb{P}\left(B\mid\mathcal{F}_{=t}\right)
  $$
- $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$, $A \in \mathcal{F}_{\leq t}$ a.s.
  $$
  \mathbb{P}\left(B\mid\mathcal{F}_{\geq t}\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(A \mid\mathcal{F}_{=t}\right)
  $$
  Looking at the first statement, I assume that it means that given a fixed ''present'', any event in the "past" and any event in the "future" are conditionally independent on each other. As far as I understand, it is actually a Markov property, so $\xi_t$ is a Markov process. However, I can't interpret the second statement, so I have no idea how to connect them and looking for help.

Comment: I think you mean $\mathbb{P}\left(A\mid\mathcal{F}_{\geq t}\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(A \mid\mathcal{F}_{=t}\right)$?

Comment: @CaveJohnson To be honest, it's not completely clear for me what do you mean here. I also have a problem of understanding this notation. I see $\mathbb{P}\left(A\mid\mathcal{F}_{\geq t}\right)$ as the probability of the event $A$ from the ''past'' given the fixed ''future''. So you want to say that the conditional probabilities of the event $A$ from the ''past'' are equal regardless of what we are given, the ''future'' or the ''present''?

Comment: Oops, I'm just confused by that you wrote $\mathbb{P}\left(B\mid\mathcal{F}_{\geq t}\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(A \mid\mathcal{F}_{=t}\right)$. On left hand side it's $B$, but on right hand side it's $A$.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Yeah, I understand, but this is the exact task :)